# drupal 7 specific page shortcuts are disappearing when edit and save that node

Tags: drupal, drupal-modules, drupal-7, shortcut

I have created a new user and I have given the rights to edit and display some specific content type, and the user has no other rights. Also I have created for him an shortcut list with some specific nodes of that type, which he has access to see and to edit.

But the strange thing is when the user (I have checked doesn't matter which user, even the administrator user) edit and save that node, then the shortcut to that node disappear from the menu bar. I have check the shortcut list attributed to that user and there is no shortcut there.

Do you experience the same thing?

---

**UPDATE**: Found a similar issue for the menu problem I'm experiencing indicating that this is a bug: http://drupal.org/node/761648#comment-4345692

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have the same trouble. It becomes very tiresome recreating my menus every time I edit content. I don't know how to fix it, but it seems the problem stems from the 'Provide a menu link' option in the Menu Settings tab while editing content. If I don't manually change it every time I edit content, it'll automatically choose to add a menu link to the main menu, deleting it from any other menu it was in. If I uncheck it, it will still delete the old menu item anyway.

I hope someone has answers!

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem with 'basic pages'.
Changed content type (structure > content types) 'basic page' and checked all the checkboxes for 'available menus'.
If you edit the content now and set the 'provide menu link' to the correct menu it remembers it correctly and the menu items don't disappear anymore.
Hope this helps.
Nephews

Answer (score 0):

Try simplifying the URLs.

One thing I've found is that if Drupal doesn't like (for whatever validation reason) your URL, it will not show it until you edit it to be acceptable.

For example, I tried adding this repeatedly without success

```
node/2/edit%3Fdestination%3Dadmin/content
```

It showed up fine when I changed it to:

```
 node/2/edit
```

Perhaps something in the node URL changes when they edit it.

Comment: I use Clean URL's in my shortcuts, however the results is the same, the shortcuts disappear when some user edit that page. I have tried to set the shortcut in Drupal default way (`node/2/edit`) and the behave is the same.  Maybe this is some Drupal 7 bug.

Answer (score -1):

It's not a real bug, but a bit strange ;)

You have to edit your content type to accept all referred menus. So, the actual menu entry won't be deleted and placed in main menu.

Have fun =)

Comment: Actually is a bug. You can check this out: http://drupal.org/node/761648#comment-4345692